# How to check if a textbox has 'x' class or not

Tags: jquery, html

I have many textboxes inside my div. I just want to know that textbox without `x` class are not empty.
How can I do this.

I have tried:

```
$("div.editorRow input").each(function () {
   //I want to check here if Textbox class is not x.
   if (!$(this).val()) {
   }
}
```

Please help me. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. Sufficient information is provided in the always-useful [jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/) I suggest you start there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the following:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('x')){
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("div.editorRow input").each(function () {
   if (! (this.value && $(this).is('.x') ) {
       // do stuff
   }else{
       // do other stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `is` vs `hasClass`?

Comment: @JamesMontagne - `hasClass()` is faster (marginally), but I just like to use `is()` as it works for everything ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$("div.editorRow input:not(.x)").each(function () {
    if (this.value == '') {
        console.log("im empty!);
    }
});
```

Comment: It would actually be `input:not(.x)` if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: @JamesMontagne -- Read it too fast! Fixed :)